# How to understand active learning QnaMaker, botframework v4

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I had read [documents](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/blog/qna-maker-simplifies-knowledge-base-management-for-your-q-a-bot/), and tried to run [Active learning sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/csharp_dotnetcore/qnamaker-activelearning-bot). I can understand how the program works.

The documents refer to Implicit feedback and Explicit feedback. I have two questions.

1. I can find the Explicit feedback' code. But I don't understand when the knowledgebase will show the feedback.
2. Implicit feedback where is the code? no code? I think both Implicit feedback and Explicit feedback have similar scores. what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as the [docs on active learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#active-learning) state, *implicit feedback* occurs when

> when a user question has multiple answers with scores that are very close,

whereas with *explicit feedback* is the feedback that is received when the

> client application asks the user which question is the correct question [and the user's selected question is used as explicit feedback

---

#### Where is the feedback collected

The feedback is collected from the conversation between user and bot.
As of now, feedback is *not* collected in the Test panel in the qnamaker.ai portal.

#### Where do we see the suggested questions generated via Active Learning?

When "enough" feedback is collected on a cluster of question and answer pair, you will see the active learning feedback inside the portal at qnamaker.ai > Edit

---

#### Further Active Learning Explanation

I'll include here one of my posts from a thread regarding Active Learning below. **I would encourage you to read the [full thread on active learning](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25638) that was opened as a Microsoft Docs issue afterwards, however, to see included screenshots.**

> @Souvik04, follow the link to the [Active Learning sample
>   bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/csharp_dotnetcore/qnamaker-activelearning-bot)
>   in the BotFramework-Samples repo for a example of how you can query
>   the QnA service from your bot with active learning enabled.
>   ___ After conversing with the QnA team (Rohit is included in the conversation), here's a little more light regarding when you would
>   actually see the suggestions inside the portal at qnamaker.ai.
>
> When there is a low confidence score difference between the top
>   answers, we collect weighted [implicit and explicit
>   feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#active-learning)
>   to cluster suggestions for any QnA ID.
>   => When *enough* feedback is collected for any given suggestion, it will show in the KB.
>
> More specifically, we cluster similar user queries to generate
>   suggestions. When minimum required feedback is collected, only then
>   will the suggestions show in the KB.
>
> The QnA team wants to avoid publicly divulging the exact logic of what
>   exactly is the "minimum required feedback" and how often suggestions
>   are generated (besides, the team is working on improving and
>   optimizing the logic behind active learning as well)
>   --however to see suggestions appear in the qnamaker.ai portal:
>   * not only ensure that you've given the bot enough **feedback**
>   * but also give the back end "some **time**" to allow for the suggestions to appear in the portal.
>
> Again, feedback is collected when your user types in a query that
>   returns answers from QnA that have confidence scores that are close
>   together.
>
> It is also good to note that feedback is *not* collected in the Test
>   panel in the qnamaker.ai portal as of now. You will need to chat with
>   your bot via emulator or a channel to provide feedback to your bot
>   that it can use for active learning.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot. But I still can not understand  "implicit feedback".  when a user question has multiple answers with scores that are very close, the bot will send answers to let the user choose. Right? To let the user choose a correct question is "implicit feedback"??

Comment: You're not seeing it as 2 separate things still, which is why you're confused. The fact that if there's a time where multiple answers return from the KB that are close together in score is in ITSELF considered the implicit feedback. However when this happens, the bot in the active learning sample is set up to ask the user to clarify the question. The user's selected question is the EXPLICIT feedback